# phpCake - find child of child

Tags: cakephp, children

I am doing some changes to a website running phpCake, where I am not totally familiar with. I tried their documentation, but unfortunately could not get a grasp on my problem.

I am trying to find an Item by id, with its children Videos, and with for each Video its child VideoThumbnail.

I have the following model configuration:

```
Item => hasMany Videos
Video => belongsTo Item
Video => hasOne VideoThumbnail
VideoThumbnail => belongsTo Video
```

I run the following code:

```
$this->Item->find('first', $options)
```

Is there something wrong in my configuration, or should I simply loop through the Videos and find the VideoThumbnails in the loop?

Thanks!

## Solution:

Use containable behavior

```
$options["contain"] = "Video.Videothumbnail";
$this->Item->find('first', $options)
```

Comment: It would be useful to tell the version you are using.

Comment: Why you added the solution to your question and didn't accept the solution of ADmad?

Comment: Sorry, I am not fully familiar with Stackoverflow. Thanks for the advice, I accepted his solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior and use `contain` option in find options to specify the associated records to fetch.

P. S. It's **CakePHP** not phpCake.

Comment: @AD7six You too sir :)